# Process to update SHA1 to SHA256 or 512

Tags: gnupg

Could you share us the step by step process to update SHA1 to SHA256 or 512:

I have made the changes in ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf. After that when I try

```
reprepro update ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf
Error opening config file './conf/distributions': No such file or directory(2)
There have been errors!
```

Please share the process to update.

When i do apt-get update, it is resulting:

```
W: https://XXXXXXXXXXXX/archive/apt/ops/InRelease: Signature by key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

I was requested to update signature key from SHA1 to SHA256 or more stronger.

I have updated **~/.gnupg/gpg.conf**

```
personal-digest-preferences SHA256
cert-digest-algo SHA256
default-preference-list SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 SHA224 AES256 AES192 AES CAST5 ZLIB BZIP2 ZIP Uncompressed
```

Not sure, what to do next. Need some help. in adjusting signature key.

Comment: Update *what* from SHA1 to SHA256/SHA512? gpg digest algorithm? [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/547335/gpg-use-sha1-even-with-digest-algo-sha512) at Superuser may give you some hints.

Comment: You should specify the base directory for `reprepro`. Also, `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` is not an argument for `reprepro`.